# How to implement MIDI player of MIDI.js for notes sequence

Tags: javascript, midi.js

I am using MIDI.js in my project, here is my code for playing sequence of MIDI notes

```
for (var repeat = 0; repeat < melodyrepititions; repeat++)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < composition.length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < composition[i].length; j++)
                {
                    if (composition[i][j] != 0)
                    {

                        MIDI.noteOn(0, composition[i][j] + scale, velocity,delay );
                        MIDI.noteOff(0, composition[i][j] + scale, delay+onlynotationsofeachbeatbracketdelay[i][j]);
                    }
                    else if (composition[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                       MIDI.noteOff(0, composition[i][j] + scale, delay);
                    }
                    delay = delay + onlynotationsofeachbeatbracketdelay[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to implement MIDI.js player for this sequence to start,pause,stop the melody while playing. I am not able to figure out how can I use MIDI.js player functions for such sequence. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

use https://github.com/surikov/SSSynthesiser.js instead of MIDI.js.

SSSynthesiser.js has full controls over what is playing. You can change in realtime all instrument samples, melody etc.

Update

this is old answer.

Use https://github.com/surikov/webaudiofont instead of it.

Read docs, look to examples. See example for MIDI-player here https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midiplayer.html

Comment: Thank you, how can I use my own instruments in SSSynthesiser.js, I dont see any option to do that

Comment: SSSynthesiser.js plays Molgav (http://molgav.nn.ru) files. It consists thousands of instruments for all purposes. Also you can add you own samples into JSON file in raw format, see example of song at project page.

Comment: I tried to understand this library, but I could not. here are some queries
1. What is molgav file?
2. From where it gets audio data, like in MIDI.js we provide soundfont js file.
2. If I want to use my own sound samples, how can I use?, please show some examples with code

Comment: 1. What is molgav file? - this is JSON file that produces Molgav service. 2. From where it gets audio data, like in MIDI.js we provide soundfont js file. - Save any song from Molgav and open it in text editor - it includes samples for all instruments used in song. Please read project description at https://github.com/surikov/SSSynthesiser.js - it has all info you need.

Comment: "this is JSON file that produces Molgav service" does it means that it will play sounds from molgav.nn.ru or is it possible to use it locally without internet connection?

Comment: you can save any song from Molgav to local file. Each file consists notes and samples. You don't need internet for music playing via SSSynthesiser.js. See project info for help.

Comment: It seems interesting, but please show me how to add my my own instrument, please refer link to to my website
http://vishwamohini.com/music/demo-tabla.php
Where you can listen tabla, which is Indian classical music instrument, how can I use this intsrument in malgov?

Comment: open any Molgav file (project example is http://molgav.nn.ru/x/sviridovtimeforward.molgav), fins a instrument sample raw data ("signed" : [0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -1, -2, -1, -1, -2, ...), replace this array with array of your sample data.

Comment: My sound data is in base64 string format for each note, please refer MIDI.js sound format, how can I convert it to sample array you have shown

Comment: this is old answer. Use https://github.com/surikov/webaudiofont instead of it. Read docs, look to examples. See example for MIDI-player here https://surikov.github.io/webaudiofont/examples/midiplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to implement MIDI player directly to sequence of notes, so solution I got is,
one need to convert sequence of notes into MIDI file & then you can input MIDI file to player. Here is link which gives more details on conversion of MIDI file

http://mudcu.be/journal/2011/11/base64-soundfonts/

Library which helps to convert sequence of notes in MIDI file
https://github.com/sergi/jsmidi